# Enumerated data type

Tags: c, enums

What is the use of the `enum` keyword ? Where can we use enumerated data-type?
Can anyone explain with an example?

Comment: anything in particular wrong with the MSDN doc? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are enumerators (ok, trivial) treated always as integers, and they are used to put in order something you could use later, like common values or indexes. But, as the name says, they are enumerated, always ascending, like:

`enum myenum {

January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December

};`

Then, if you have an array, say:

```
int months[12][30];
```

You can call your months using:

```
months[March][...];
```

Also, if you declare:

```
enum myenum {  January = 1, February, March, ..., };
```

This your program will start the counter of the enumeration from 1 and so on.

Finally, about this last rule: you can set initial values as you want, e.g., 10, 20, 30, 42 etc., but you can also set one of the enumerated values and let others be sorted by default.

Comment: Note that most people will find January = 0 and December = 11 confusing...the C time structures are atrocious for this.

Answer (score 6):

An `enum` gives a name to a number.

```
enum { MAX_LINES = 60 };
```

Superficially, so does a `#define`:

```
#define MAX_LINES 60
```

The benefit of an `enum` over a `#define` is that the name is recorded in the debugging information, so the debugger can use it.

You can also use an `enum` to define a set of related values:

```
typedef enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE } Colour;
```

You might then use these to index into a triplet array for the RGB values:

```
typedef unsigned char Pixel[3];

Pixel p;

p[RED]   = 128;
p[GREEN] = 128;
p[BLUE]  = 255;
```

Probably not the world's best example, but an indication of where an `enum` can be used.

Comment: don't need to typedef it. `enum foo { bar, baz};` will do.

Comment: @Alex: in the code shown, where I don't have a 'Colour' variable, you're correct.  I prefer to use just 'Colour' over 'enum Colour' when declaring variables, though, so I prefer a typedef.

Comment: in C, fair enough -- in C++ that's handled for you automatically.

Comment: My favorite enum is `enum bool { false, true };` but that's a personal preference.

Comment: @Chris: wassup with ``#include <stdbool.h>`'?  Yeah, I know; inertia...I don't use it either.

Comment: @Jonathan - `stdbool.h` is good, but it just so easy to write a workaround in case someone doesn't have it that I do it out of habit.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm a huge fan of this `Color` / `Pixel` thing you've invented. It is quite clever.

Answer (score 0):

enums are introduced at the time of "ANSI C" (or c89) the basic syntax is

```
enum type {
 item1,
 item2,
 item3
};
```

It takes value starting from 0, item1 will hold 0, item2=1, item3=2.. Until if you tell the compiler what value it should start from,

```
enum type {
 item1 = 10,
 item2,
 item3
};
```

then the values are, item1=10, item2=11, item=12.. Also the compiler will consider them as integers.

```
int i=10;
i += item1;
```

which is

```
i = i + 10;
```

You can also define a variable of the type enum.

```
enum type mytype;
mytype = item1;
```

In this case the variable item1 is converted (silently) to the type "enum type". You can mix the variable of type "enum type" with integer.

```
mytype = i;
mytype = mytype + 100;
```

though the variable mytype is of type "enum type" its also considered as integer hence it can hold any integer variable. 
But IMO, enums should be used as constants and should not be involved in arithmetic operation and leave the compiler to decided the value on itself rather than assigning a value.

Comment: Technically, they were introduced a few years before the C89 standard, but they were introduced after the 1st Edition of K&R.

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration is a list of constant integer values, as in

```
enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
```

The first name in an enum has value 0, the next 1, and so on, unless explicit values are specified. If not all values are specified, unspecified values continue the progression from the last specified value:

```
enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC };
```

As a `char` is internally represented using an integer, you can declare enumerations that point to character constants as well:

```
enum whitespaces { SPACE = ' ', TAB = ’\t’, NEWLINE = ’\n’, RETURN = ’\r’ };
```

An advantage of enumeration over `#define` is that the values can be generated for you. In addition, a debugger may be able to print values of enumeration variables in their symbolic form.